# "Не()использованные" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Неиспользованные по путевке дни можете не фиксировать в заявлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Неиспользованный* — это полная форма причастия. Согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §150. С полными формами причастий отрицание *не* пишется **раздельно**
>
> а) если при них имеются зависимые слова;
>
> б) в составе конструкций с противопоставлением или конструкций, усиливающих отрицание.

В вашем примере *по путевке* является зависимым словом, поэтому причастие пишется раздельно:

*Не использованные по путевке дни можете не фиксировать в заявлении.*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Если Вы Лопатина **цитируете**, то правильно надо бы так: _§ 150. С полными формами причастий отрицание **не** пишется раздельно: а) если при них имеются зависимые слова..._ (http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=76). Нужно убрать знак цитирования и поставить перед "если" запятую. "По путевке" — с большой буквы. Вы ведь на сайте _русского языка_ и уже не новый участник — чтобы бесконечно править. Поддерживайте сами свою репутацию. (А уж про тире я стоически помалкиваю.)